# How to extract only parent and version from get broswer

Tags: php

How to get only the browser parent and version only from this array.I am confused about iterating through an array.I have tried something like  $broswer['parent'] its not worked for me.

```
  $browser = get_browser();
    var_dump($browser);
  public 'browser_name_regex' => string '§^mozilla/5\.0 \(.*windows nt 6\.2.*wow64.*\) applewebkit/.* \(khtml, like gecko\).*chrome/33\..*safari/.*$§' (length=108)
  public 'browser_name_pattern' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (*Windows NT 6.2*WOW64*) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML, like Gecko)*Chrome/33.*Safari/*' (length=90)
  public 'parent' => string 'Chrome 33.0' (length=11)
  public 'platform' => string 'Win8' (length=4)
  public 'platform_version' => string '6.2' (length=3)
  public 'win32' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'win64' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'comment' => string 'Chrome 33.0' (length=11)
  public 'version' => string '33.0' (length=4)
  public 'majorver' => string '33' (length=2)
  public 'cssversion' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 'browser' => string 'Chrome' (length=6)
  public 'frames' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'iframes' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'tables' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'cookies' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'javascript' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'javaapplets' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'minorver' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'alpha' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'beta' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'win16' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'backgroundsounds' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'vbscript' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'activexcontrols' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'ismobiledevice' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'istablet' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'issyndicationreader' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'crawler' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'aolversion' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Use

```
$browser = get_browser();
echo $browser->parent;
```

Or

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser['parent'];
```